# Unity RB Controller Jitter on a Moving Platform

Tags: unity, camera, moving-platforms, cinemachine

**Brief Description:** I have a RB based character controller that I want to move along with my Train platform (non physics based) when the player steps on it.

[image]

**Main Problem**
I manage to make the player follow the platform, but I also have a **camera jitter problem** that I can't solve without breaking player follow the Train platform logic.

**Video showing the jitter.**

**Important:** I'm not getting any jitter when only moving the camera

**Important:** I'm not getting any jitter when only moving the Character without moving the camera

this applies to both when the player is on a moving platform, or off the platform

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9M4dt00dEes

**My Camera Implementation**

For handling the camera I'm using Cinemachine, alongside a CameraHolder which is a separate gameobject from the player.

I'm setting the transform of the cameraHolder Gameobject to the players position in late Update

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = cameraPosition.position;
}
```

[image]

The Headbob Offset gameobject is a child in the cameraHolder without any movement.

**Player Controller Movement**

I'm using this code in FixedUpdate to handle my player movement

```
    private void HandleMovement()
{
    //old input system
    //float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    //float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    //Vector2 movementDir = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical).normalized;

    //New input system
    movementDir = GameInput.instance.GetMovementVectorNormalised();
    Vector3 currentVelocity = rb.velocity;
    Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(movementDir.x, 0, movementDir.y);
    targetVelocity *= speed;

    targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity);

    Vector3 velocityChange = targetVelocity - currentVelocity;
    velocityChange = new Vector3(velocityChange.x, 0, velocityChange.z);

    Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocityChange, maxForce);

    rb.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

RB interpolation is set to Interpolate

**Train Platform Movement Script**

```
private void FixedUpdate() 
{
transform.position += transform.forward * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

**Important** I'm using FixedUpdate, but my train platform has no RB on it, I'm using FixedUpdate, because otherwise my player doesn't follow the train position change.

**What I've Tried so far**

**1. Lerping Camera Position**

Instead of setting the camera position to the cameraHolder, I tried lerping. It solved the overall jitter in the game, but my whole train platform became jiterry when moving.

```
        private void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, cameraPosition.position, lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Videos showing the problem

jitter almost solved https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxXXk_oVpsg
Train jitter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85biDT_nl_4

**2. Add dumping to Cinemachine virtual camera**

results are the same as with lerping. everything else is smooth besides the train

[image]

I'll provide any necessary information if I haven't mentioned something here

Answer (score 0):

Changing FixedTimeStep to 0.01 from 0.02 resolved the jitter issue!